# js-doc / google-closure-compiler how to document passed enum object itself?

Tags: javascript, enums, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

e.g.

```
/**
 * Super my enum
 * @enum {number}
 */
var MyEnum = {
    ONE: 1,
    TWO: 2
};

/**
 * @param {what type is it?} enumObj
 */
function showEnum(enumObj) {
  console.log(enumObj);
}

//show the enum definition object
showEnum(MyEnum);
```

how to describe parameter type as not the value/instance of `MyEnum`, but as the `MyEnum`  object itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use `!MyEnum` where the `!` means "non-null".

```
/**
* @param {!MyEnum} enumObj
*/
function showEnum(enumObj) {
  console.log(enumObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution i tested in WebStorm and VSCode for autocompletion is to use `typeof MyEnum`.
Its still invalid JSDoc, but supported for autocompletion by IDEs.

```
/**
 * @param {typeof MyEnum} enumObj
 */
function showEnum(enumObj) {
  console.log(enumObj);
}
```